# Select with un-standard Group by in clause

Tags: mysql, sql

sorry if I reinventing the wheel (and for my English too), and maybe is not possible with plain vanilla query but I have "nonsence Idea" that is possible move block of Rows to Resulsets top, I hope that this SQL dump (MySql) and for better undestood I converted that to the Account and its Currency, maybe these would be better to ilustrate what I trying, really clause Group by with Order by not my cup of java

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `account`;

CREATE TABLE `account` (
  `idAccount` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idCustomer` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `idCustomerNumber` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AccountNumber` varchar(12) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Currency` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idAccount`)
) 

INSERT INTO `account` (`idAccount`,`idCustomer`,`idCustomerNumber`,`AccountNumber`,`Currency`) VALUES 
 (1,1,'000001','000001JPY101','JPY'),
 (2,1,'100002','100002GBP101','GBP'),
 (3,2,'003333','003333EUR201','EUR'),
 (4,1,'100002','100002GBP102','GBP'),
 (5,1,'000001','000001EUR101','EUR'),
 (6,1,'000001','000001USD101','USD'),
 (7,1,'000001','000001USD102','USD'),
 (8,1,'100002','100002EUR101','EUR'),
 (9,1,'100002','100002USD101','USD'),
 (10,2,'003333','003333EUR202','EUR'),
 (11,2,'003333','003333JPY201','JPY');
```

(`Select * From Account Where CustomerNumber = '000001'`)

EDIT: now I hope that would be better ...

how can I create Select from table with Group by Currenncy and Order by AccountNumber, and with possibility to create Resultset starts with for example AccountNumbers with USD currency, rest of rows would be alphabetically grouped by currency and ordered by AccountNumber

to extract a rows that would be sorted with follows order USD - EUR - JPY

Edit 2:

my bad, sorry for that, really time to start to learn the major language

basically if I call `SELECT * FROM Account Where idCustomerNumber = '000001' Order by Currency, AccountNumber` then SQL interpreter returns

```
5,1,"000001","000001EUR101","EUR"
1,1,"000001","000001JPY101","JPY"
6,1,"000001","000001USD101","USD"
7,1,"000001","000001USD102","USD"
```

but now I want to programmatically determine that Resulset starts with USD accounts and rest of account would be Group by Currency then Order by AccountNumber

Comment: I don't understand your question, because of grammar and strange sentences. Please try to improve it.

Comment: this Tag is just for correctness as I mentioned in contents java.sql.Resulset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear what you want. Perhaps this?:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    account
WHERE
    idCustomerNumber = '000001'
ORDER BY
    Currency = 'USD'  DESC
  , Currency
  , AccountNumber ;
```

Comment: simple, correct and sufficient syntax for my requirement, this code works with my additional Group by too, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help you:

```
 SELECT * FROM account
 WHERE idCustomerNumber = '000001'
 ORDER BY AccountNumber, CASE WHEN Currency = 'USD' THEN 0 WHEN Currency = 'EUR' THEN 1 WHEN Currency = 'JPY' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
```

Usually when you are trying to group on you need to consider what you are going to do with the columns that you combine on, for grouping you need to use summary values, eg: lets assume you have an Amount column:

```
 SELECT AccountNumber, Currency, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount FROM account
 WHERE idCustomerNumber = '000001'
 GROUP BY AccountNumber, Currency
 ORDER BY AccountNumber, CASE WHEN Currency = 'USD' THEN 0 WHEN Currency = 'EUR' THEN 1 WHEN Currency = 'JPY' THEN 2 ELSE 0 END
```

As for the sorting by USD then EUR then JPY and so on, this would best be defined in a CurrencySortOrder table so that you can add further values without having to change all your queries and such.